# Restricting user to enter a max 5 digit integer with max 2 decimals in angular 2 with ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a input text field which contains [(ngModel)] and my requirement is to allow user only enter max 5 digit number with upto 2 decimals.Creating a directive is a best solution but I am not aware of how to bring this functionality. Please help.

the requirement is - 99999.99 is correct
                        99.9 is also correct.

I used number pipe [ngModel]="cost |number:'1.0-2' but it is not working..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern attribute of the `<input>` to validate your entry. I added a pattern for what you asked, positive/negative, 0 to 5 digits, 0 to 2 decimals:

`<input name="something" pattern="^[-+]?\d{0,5}(\.\d{0,2})?$">`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in two ways. Template driven forms and in Reactive forms. Please find the below example which give some idea about how validation works.

**In the TS file: ( Template Driven Forms)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sandboxngforms',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <!-- by default html5 has validation. if u add a directive called "novalidate" in form tag
    then we can build our customised template.
    create an id called f so that we can easily group-->

    <!--group the form by value id #f instead of submit> use ngSubmit so that u can use the values used in the form and call the function -->

    <form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="user.name"
          name="name"
          #userName="ngModel"
          minlength="2"
          required>
        <!-- using the name input field #tagid (i.e userName) write the below if condition 
        touched is a special directive that allows u when u click on the field and click outside
        will produce error-->

        <div *ngIf="userName.errors?.required && userName.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Name is required</div>
        <div *ngIf="userName.errors?.minlength && userName.touched"
             class="alert alert-danger">Name should be at least 2 characters
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="user.email"
          name="email"
          #userEmail="ngModel"
          required
        >
        <div *ngIf="userEmail.errors?.required && userEmail.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Email is required</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="user.phone"
          name="phone"
          #userPhone="ngModel"
          minlength="10"
        >
        <div *ngIf="userPhone.errors?.minlength && userPhone.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Enter a valid phone
          number
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
    </form>
  `
})
export class SandboxngformsComponent {
// create an user object
  user = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  }

  onSubmit({value, valid}) {
    if (valid) {
      console.log(value);
    } else {
      console.log('Form is invalid');
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps